# What is the output of this code with explanation?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int a[4][5] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                  { 6, 7, 8, 9,10 },
                  {11,12,13,14,15 },
                  {16,17,18,19,20 } };
  printf("%d\n", *(*(a + **a + 2) + 3));
  return 0;
}
```

The above code gives 19 as answer. I want to know how does it calculates.

Comment: Why don't you try breaking it down and analyzing the sub expressions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you made an attempt at solving this? If so, how did it go? I recommend breaking it down into steps--print `**a`, then `a + **a + 2` and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets do it one step at a time:

- `**a` is `a[0][0]` which is `1`
- `a + 1 + 2` is `&a[3]`
- `*(&a[3])` is `a[3]`
- `*(a[3] + 3)` is `a[3][3]` which is `19`.

QED